# Firestore goal tracker database modeling

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to model my flutter firebase app, that will consist of tracking users goal/habits (kind of a todo app) and users can share their own goals and others can add them to become their goals and we can see for example where everyone is progressing on a specific goal for example :

- John : 5/7 days checked
- William : 3/7 days checked

This is an example of the modal I came with for now, I don't know if I should add a list of "members" for example for adding users that add this goal to their or duplicating the goal itself, the main thing is to watch the progress of all users who added that goal

[image: Modal example]

Comment: Are you planning to do this in real time database or firestore ?

Comment: Hello, in firestore

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understood what you can do is create an user collection and goals collection separately.

- Register each user under user collection using there auth uid {document} and relevant data.

So if you want to fetch user data all you can do is :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(auth.uid).get() and further logic
```

[image: User Collection model]

- While in other hand while registering / tracking goals of the users keep all the goals under single collection with a name you prefer {I prefered it as *goals*} and as you defined additional parameter as owner of the goal pass the user UID as you described.
- For the part how are you gonna access the data -

  - Lets consider I am a user and I have some goals I set, as you can see I am keeping the goals of all users under the same collection. So to fetch the goals for specific user I can do

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('goals').where('owner', isEqual: auth.uid)
```

and get this stream as my user specific goals.

- Now second scenario lets suppose I am a user and I want to share the goals to all of the users who are using the app simply I can add one more field to my goals collection as *visibility : public/private*. So while on a screen where I am fetching goals all over the world (basically goals which are made public to all of the app users) I can write query as

```
irebaseFirestore.instance.collection('goals').where('visibility', isEqual:'public')
```

- In third scenario lets say you want to send your goals to specific user you can maintain an array of uids you have added in your goals field as *access* so you can see shared goals by

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('goals').where('access', arrayContains: auth.uid)
```

[image]

- And last suggestion is time stamping the goals this will help you to fetch the newer goals in order using queries.

I hope it is so much easy than I explained